# M2E Pro doesn't include Magento Tax rules in eBay item prices

Tags: configuration, xcommerce

I'm having trouble with M2E Pro and the way that it lists items on eBay without applying the Magento Tax rules setup for those products.

Here's a link to the M2E Pro documentation for general reference: http://docs.m2epro.com/display/eBayAmazonMagentoV42/M2E+Pro

There doesn't seem to be a solution to listing products and applying the Magento tax rules bar using the 'Price Change' option (within M2E Pro Selling Format Template) on the products to add a tax value. Doing that could cause issues when orders are created in Magento from eBay though because the tax is added to the order.

Price change docs here: http://docs.m2epro.com/display/eBayAmazonMagentoV42/M2E+Pro

The store I'm dealing with doesn't have the tax applied to product prices when they're entered, and Magento handles VAT on product prices through a tax class.

Anyone with any ideas?

Cheers,

Mark.

Comment: I think that this question may have a home here, but we'll need maybe a bit of background info on how this works (link or explanation would help).

Comment: @benmarks Hopefully that's a bit better now. Does it make a bit more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Tax rules typically apply based on the location of the buyer, so it would not normally make sense to have tax rules be applied to a product's price before exporting/synchronizing it with another sales channel. Unless I'm completely missing the point, the customer wouldn't be charged the correct tax rate this way, and they wouldn't know they were even being charged sales tax.

My suggestion is to look into using a [tax table](http://pages.ebay.com/help/pay/checkout-tax-table.html) on eBay, then test to see how M2E handles an order placed with a tax charge, or write their support team and see if they can tell you.

Comment: You make a good point about location based tax settings. Unfortunately, I can't see any docs or tools to setup a tax table for the UK marketplace on eBay. It may be possible if running a store rather than a business account.  The store I'm working on only sells within the UK anyway. I just expected M2E Pro to have more options available for handling tax on products.  Tbh, M2E Pro's support was poor. They just explained I'd have to use a price change option, but they didn't explain why tax doesn't get applied to product when listed which wasn't much help.